# Best way to build a secure RESTful web service layer accessed from ajax front end & api requests

Tags: ajax, session, authentication, rest, resteasy

I have a jax-rs web service layer built with jboss resteasy. All the web services consume and produce json objects. I need to secure this layer to handle requests coming from separate sources.

The ws can be accessed by an ajax front end with form based login. Therefore I need to store the user session on the server and check the existence of it on every ws request.

Moreover, I'd like to expose the web services through a REST API using some sort of HMAC (without OAuth) authentication.

Does anybody know a solution to achieve it? It would be great to have a centralized authorization component that could handle the requests from both sources.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a JSR-196 based provider that would handle both use cases for you, then configure that for both end points. May need to add some discriminator so that the service would know how to authenticate a random request (could be configured in the provider based on the URL, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the 100% best way to handle this, but I had a similar problem.  I will share it in case you find that it applies. (I am not familiar with resteasy)  Basically there were existing REST web service that our mobile platforms plugged into.  I was asked to display some data from the mobile services to our web app that had forms authentication.

The solution was to take the FormsAuthentication cookie and add it to the header of the request that you are sending to the service and the service will decrypt that cookie to get the user that is making the request.

This is making 2 assumptions:  1. That both your service and your web app are using the same encryption keys and 2. that once you log in via FormsAuth your service doesnt have to fully authenticate the users credentials again.  So the service is just basically saying "Can I decrypt the token? and is this a valid user?"